# Duplicate error on value.xml file in Android Studio 4.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appcompat, android-sdk-tools

I'm trying to develop an app with android studio 4.1.1 and it has almost done but there is an error in the value.xml file from appcompat 1.2.0 and material 1.2.1.
after i hit the build project to device these errors shows up in the log.
Here is some info about my config:

```
compile sdk version : 30
min sdk version : 21
buildToolsVersion : 30.0.2
ndkVersion : 21.0.6113669
```

Error codes:

```
C:\Users\**\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0e1355bd10f51465d015cd38c7b32cb\material-1.2.1\res\values\values.xml:2539:5-2577:23: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/layout_scrollFlags' with config ''.
    
C:\Users\**\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0e1355bd10f51465d015cd38c7b32cb\material-1.2.1\res\values\values.xml:2539:5-2577:23: AAPT: error: resource previously defined here.
    
C:\Users\**\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0e1355bd10f51465d015cd38c7b32cb\material-1.2.1\res\values\values.xml:2578:5-2597:23: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/badgeGravity' with config ''.
    
C:\Users\**\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0e1355bd10f51465d015cd38c7b32cb\material-1.2.1\res\values\values.xml:2578:5-2597:23: AAPT: error: resource previously defined here.
    
C:\Users\**\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0e1355bd10f51465d015cd38c7b32cb\material-1.2.1\res\values\values.xml:2598:5-2631:23: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/fabAlignmentMode' with config ''.
    
C:\Users\**\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0e1355bd10f51465d015cd38c7b32cb\material-1.2.1\res\values\values.xml:2598:5-2631:23: AAPT: error: resource previously defined here.
```

and :

```
C:\Users\**\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\3a673510e337bf69bd102ca32d6fbb05\appcompat-1.2.0\res\values\values.xml:1692:5-1774:25: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/navigationMode' with config ''.
    
C:\Users\**\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\3a673510e337bf69bd102ca32d6fbb05\appcompat-1.2.0\res\values\values.xml:1692:5-1774:25: AAPT: error: resource previously defined here.
    
C:\Users\**\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\3a673510e337bf69bd102ca32d6fbb05\appcompat-1.2.0\res\values\values.xml:1692:5-1774:25: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/displayOptions' with config ''.
    
C:\Users\**\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\3a673510e337bf69bd102ca32d6fbb05\appcompat-1.2.0\res\values\values.xml:1692:5-1774:25: AAPT: error: resource previously defined here.
    
C:\Users\**\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\3a673510e337bf69bd102ca32d6fbb05\appcompat-1.2.0\res\values\values.xml:1819:5-1848:25: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/tintMode' with config ''.
    
C:\Users\**\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\3a673510e337bf69bd102ca32d6fbb05\appcompat-1.2.0\res\values\values.xml:1819:5-1848:25: AAPT: error: resource previously defined here.
    
C:\Users\**\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\3a673510e337bf69bd102ca32d6fbb05\appcompat-1.2.0\res\values\values.xml:1849:5-1875:25: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/tickMarkTintMode' with config ''.
    
C:\Users\**\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\3a673510e337bf69bd102ca32d6fbb05\appcompat-1.2.0\res\values\values.xml:1849:5-1875:25: AAPT: error: resource previously defined here.
    
C:\Users\**\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\3a673510e337bf69bd102ca32d6fbb05\appcompat-1.2.0\res\values\values.xml:1885:5-1959:25: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/autoSizeTextType' with config ''.
    
C:\Users\**\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\3a673510e337bf69bd102ca32d6fbb05\appcompat-1.2.0\res\values\values.xml:1885:5-1959:25: AAPT: error: resource previously defined here.
    
C:\Users\**\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\3a673510e337bf69bd102ca32d6fbb05\appcompat-1.2.0\res\values\values.xml:1885:5-1959:25: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/drawableTintMode' with config ''.
    
C:\Users\**\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\3a673510e337bf69bd102ca32d6fbb05\appcompat-1.2.0\res\values\values.xml:1885:5-1959:25: AAPT: error: resource previously defined here.
    
C:\Users\**\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\3a673510e337bf69bd102ca32d6fbb05\appcompat-1.2.0\res\values\values.xml:1960:5-2356:25: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/actionBarSize' with config ''.
    
C:\Users\**\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\3a673510e337bf69bd102ca32d6fbb05\appcompat-1.2.0\res\values\values.xml:1960:5-2356:25: AAPT: error: resource previously defined here.
```

and also :

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource compilation failed
     C:\Users\**\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\3a673510e337bf69bd102ca32d6fbb05\appcompat-1.2.0\res\values\values.xml:1692:5-1774:25: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/navigationMode' with config ''.
```

my values.xml file link in zip file:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/ewu4d91g5ovl4o0/values.zip/file

Comment: please share your value.xml file

Answer (score 0):

Just keep reducing the version of the dependency mentioned in the path 
In your case its: 
  *C:\Users.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a0e1355bd10f51465d015cd38c7b32cb\ **material-1.2.1** \res\values\values.xml*  
and
*C:\Users.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\3a673510e337bf69bd102ca32d6fbb05\ **appcompat-1.2.0** \res\values\values.xml*
 So reducing the version number for **material-1.2.1** to **material-1.2.0** and **appcompat-1.2.0** to **1.1.0** might work. 
If it doesn't work then keep on reducing the version number and re-build the project each time until it works.
For me it works by setting **material-1.2.1** to **material-1.0.0**